# Basic Shapes Union / Intersection / Difference : too blind to see?

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I'm new to ARKit and after inspecting some example code like https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip I wondered if there is **any** posibility to construct geometries in a "union / intersection / difference"-manner from primitives.

The following pseudo code should illustrate:

```
SCNBox *boxGeometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1.0 height:1.0 length:1.0];
SCNSphere *sphereGeometry = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:0.6];

SCNGeometry *sphereUnionBox = [SCNGeometry union:sphereGeometry with:boxGeometry];
SCNGeometry *sphereAndBoxIntersection = [SCNGeometry intersect:sphereGeometry and:boxGeometry];
SCNGeometry *sphereSubstractedFromBox = [SCNGeometry substract:sphereGeometry from:boxGeometry];
SCNGeometry *boxSubstractedFromSphere = [SCNGeometry substract:boxGeometry from:sphereGeometry];
```

which should lead (after construction nodes from these geometries and adding them to the scene) to the well-known and familiar combinations:

[image]

Any broad hint would be appreciated, I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit doesn't offer APIs for constructive solid geometry (CSG). There are `SCNGeometry` APIs to build completely custom geometries, but you would have to figure out the list of vertices and triangles yourself.

Comment: thank you for that clear answer, somehow I already guessed it

Comment: Among built-in Apple APIs, Model I/O offers the closest to what you're looking for — it does CSG operations, but only on [voxels](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlvoxelarray). (Not arbitrary meshes or analytic/parametric geometry like ideal spheres.)

Comment: Hey @mnuages, thank you so much for your detailed answers! I and my team stuck on an issue for days ah :/ I posted an interesting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662318/arkit-apply-filter-cifilter-to-a-specific-part-vertex-of-an-arfaceanchor Would love your suggestions!